# Performance issue with Ionic 3 Slides animation on Android device

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I have slides to display over **200** photos of resolution = **1700x1700**.
When scrolling in ionic lab (`ionic serve --lab`) the sliding is smooth and perfect but not in my **android** phone (it freezes a bit to go from slide 1 to 80 for example.

Here is the piece of code.

```
<ion-slides (ionSlideTap)="showHideNavBar($event)" centeredSlides effect="slide"
      spaceBetween=25 speed=500 zoom=true>
      <!-- Slide of the cover-->
      <ion-slide>
        <img src={{titlePath}}/>
      </ion-slide>
      <!-- Slides of the rest of the page -->
      <ion-slide *ngFor="let th of pagesPaths; let i = index"
      [ngClass]="(i%2 ==0)?'rightShadow':'leftShadow'">
        <img [src]=th class="images" />
      </ion-slide>
    </ion-slides>
```

**UPDATE:**

After hours of searching and tries, I discovered that animation problem with Ionic apps on Android device is an old unresolved problem.
Any help would be very apprecited!

Comment: Sure, it will be lag. So consider to use ion-img or vituralScroll to better perfomance

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But virtualScroll is not designed to work with ion-slides (as far as I know). And ion-img is not properly working

Comment: In addition, I read that: ion-img is only meant to be used inside of virtual-scroll

Comment: I think you should write your own slides with custom next and prev button, then dynamic add and remove image with button click event. Seem like virtualScroll can not work with ion-slides